# Неправильно отображаются эллементы меню при включённой поддержке appcompat v7 support

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть активность содержащая меню из двух элементов с таким кодом:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.action_create_order:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, OrderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

         case R.id.action_settings:

            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
   }
}
```

И разметкой меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <item
      android:id="@+id/action_create_order"
      android:orderInCategory="1"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_event"
      android:title="@string/action_create_order"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

   <item
      android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Включена зависимость com.android.support:v7-25.1.0.

В меню должны показываться item с индексом action_create_order, что и показано на превью в android studio:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при запуске приложения обведённый красным значок уходит в текстовый список элементов (тот который открывается по нажатию на три точки или на кнопку меню на телефоне).

P.s. Не могу прикрепить больше одной картинки т.к. недавно на stackoverflow, a для того, чтобы прикрепить две ссылки, надо минимум 10 очков доверенности.

Comment: Замените в  `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` ifRoom на always

Comment: при использовании библиотеки appcompat и её темы следует наследоваться от AppCompatActivity во избежании всяких непонятностей в интерфейсе